# Wordpress edit Button in Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am working on my first wordpress website.
Using the Botiga Version: 1.0.5 By aThemes.
Problem, at the end of every page is a edit link, which i don't need.
Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: The Edit link will only be shown when you're logged in. You can also take a look at [this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22591/how-to-remove-all-instances-of-edit-post-link) for options on how to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way to do it:
Create child theme https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ or download my child theme - https://github.com/snuffybg/Botiga-Child-theme.git . There you will find 2 files one is style.css and functions.php where you will see overwritten get_edit_post_link() function.

Edit your parent theme ( if you update you will have to add the changes again)

In your theme go to functions.php and add following

```
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'my_edit_post_link');
function my_edit_post_link() {
    return;
}
```

Or go through all template files and remove/comment following code

```
edit_post_link(
    sprintf(
        wp_kses(
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
            __( 'Edit <span class="screen-reader-text">%s</span>', 'botiga' ),
            array(
                'span' => array(
                    'class' => array(),
                ),
            )
        ),
        wp_kses_post( get_the_title() )
    ),
    '<span class="edit-link">',
    '</span>'
);
```

Or in your css add following code.

```
footer.entry-footer {display:none}
```

This wont remove it just hide it.